# How can I call a multidatepicker jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using `MultiDatesPicker v1.6.1 for jQuery UI` in my project, but I got a error.

I do my `<input type='text'>` dynamically

```
 icones = "<input type='text' id='datacurso_" + drv["Usuario_Id"].ToString() + "' onclick='javascript:chamaData(this.id)'  />";
```

**RENDERED**

```
<input id="datacurso_3636" onclick="javascript:chamaData(this.id)" type="text"/>
```

and in my `<script>` I call my function called `chamaData` passing the id.

```
function chamaData(id) {
        $("#" + id).multiDatesPicker({  maxPicks: 2 });
}
```

but I got an error when I click in my `<input type='text'>`

**Error**

```
Microsoft JScript: Conversion from "string" format not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker
```

Somebody can help me ?

The idea, is when I click in my `<input type='text'>` the datepicker shows

Comment: switch `'` and `"` in your html string.

Comment: @Johan, I will replace for which character ?

Comment: Something like this `'<input type="text" id="datacurso_'` etc...

Comment: Occurrs the error `Too many charachters in a literal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face an error on my project but it looks like a conflict. 
Check this **http://jsbin.com/ahebuy/1/watch** - it's example with minimal number of libraries

In my case it was a conflict with jquery.tablesorter.js

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem does not come from `multiDatesPicker`. We must look if a portion of the js code before `multiDatePicker`. I had a `Array.prototype` just before what made the bug... then do the testes and comment out the js code that runs before `multiDatesPicker`.

Everything works for me now.